# reorder function within mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying this code:

```
crowdfund_tweets_clean %>%
  top_n(15) %>%
  mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = word, y = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab(NULL) +
  coord_flip() +
    labs(x = "Count",
         y = "Unique words",
         title = "Count of Unique Words found in Tweets")
```

And getting the following error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `word`. i `word = reorder(word, n)`. x arguments must have same length

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  To help us to help would you mind sharing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: ... this said. One likely reason which gives rise to this error is that your dataframe does not contain a column named `n`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fct_reorder` from `forcats` package:
Here is an example:

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
  top_n(15) %>%
  mutate(gear = factor(gear)) %>% 
  add_count(gear) %>% 
  mutate(mpg = fct_reorder(gear, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = gear, y = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab(NULL) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "Count",
       y = "Unique words",
       title = "Count of Unique Words found in Tweets")
```

[image]